# Convergence/Stability of SDE that depends on an ergodic process

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Let the following stochastic system be given

$$dX_t=-X_t \, dt+dW_t,$$
$$dY_t=Y_t(1-Y_t)X_t(dt+dV_t),$$

where $W_t$ and $V_t$ are independent Wiener processes, $X_0\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1/2)$ (the stationary measure), and $Y_0=1/2$.

Simulations suggest that $Y_t\rightarrow Y_\infty$ almost surely, where $Y_\infty$ is a random variable that takes the values $0$ and $1$ each with probability $1/2$.
How can this be proved?

Alternatively, convergence in probability would also work, but if possible I'm interested in the strongest possible result.
Also, can we relax the conditions on $X_t$ to be an arbitrary ergodic Markov process?

---

Currently, all the answers contain major gaps that need to be fixed.
Alternative ways of proving the statement are very welcome, in particular very principled or general methods of tackling this problem.
Please also note the more general version of this problem posted [here on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287418/stochastic-stability-of-open-continuous-time-stochastic-systems-reference-req).

---

My original idea of a proof was the following:

1. Show that the sample limit exists almost surely, i.e. show that $A=\{\omega: \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}Y_t(\omega)\text{ exists}\}$ is measurable and that
   $$\mathbb{P}(A)=1.$$
2. Show that the limit is in $\{0,1\}$ almost surely if it exists
   $$\mathbb{P}(Y_{\infty}=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}Y_t\in\{0,1\}|A)=1.$$
   Because of 1), we have
   $$\mathbb{P}(Y_{\infty}\in\{0,1\})=\mathbb{P}(Y_{\infty}=0)+\mathbb{P}(Y_{\infty}=1)=1.$$
3. Make a symmetry argument for why $\mathbb{P}(Y_{\infty}=0)=\mathbb{P}(Y_{\infty}=1)=1/2$.

Comment: $Y_t\in[0,1]$. If you put coefficients in front of $dW$ and $dV$ and tune them, what happens?

Comment: Increasing the coefficients in front of either $dW$ or $dV$ seems to change the rate of the convergence but does not seem to change whether or not $Y_t$ stays within $[0,1]$. As far as I can see, $Y_t\in[0,1]$ for all $t\geq 0$ almost surely is guaranteed by the continuity of the sample paths of $Y_t$ and the fact that $dY_t=0$ if $Y_t\in\{0,1\}$. Thus if one supposes that $Y_0\in[0,1]$ and $Y_t\notin[0,1]$ for some $t>0$, one gets a contradiction at the $0<s<t$ where $Y_s\in\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Maybe the limit in which the coefficient of $dV$ goes to zero is helpful: in that case, the solution to $\dot Y_t=Y_t(1-Y_t)X_t$ is $Y_t=(1+\exp[-\int_0^t X_s ds])^{-1}$. So $Y_t\rightarrow 1$ iff $\int_0^t X_s ds\rightarrow\infty$ and $Y_t\rightarrow 0$ iff $\int_0^t X_s ds\rightarrow-\infty$.

Comment: I am NOT questioning $Y_t\in[0,1]$, but STATING it, as the first sentence of my last comment ends with a period not a question mark. This is guaranteed by the uniqueness the SDE solution and, as you say, the continuity of the sample path.

Setting the coefficients to zero is exactly what I imply. I have some idea and am typing it up right now.

Comment: I understand. I'm looking forward to your further suggestions!

Comment: Fix $X_t$ and just look at the second SDE, the one for $dY_t$. The terminal distribution will be $c_1(x)\delta(y)+c_2(x)\delta(1-y)$. Could you run lots of simulation to get $c_1(x)$ and $c_2(x)$ as functions of $x$?

Comment: This can be done, but afterwards it is not clear to me how to connect this to the invariant measure of the system. There are some SDEs for $X_t$ for which the invariant measure of $Y_t$ is not concentrated at {0,1}.

Comment: I just want to see how the second equation behaves, first. Can you give some examples of the first, or $dX_t$, SDE's where the terminal or invariant measure does not concentrate at $\{0,1\}$? In fact can you try $X_t=a\sin(\omega t)$ with different $(a,\omega)$'s? I would not expect the size of $\omega$ to have much impact. I am also looking at pseudo-analytic function which may offer a way to analyze the 2-d elliptical PDE with power series analogous to that (Frobenius method) in the ODE. You may want to look into that as well. Let me know if you find something first.

Comment: When $dX_t=0$, we can form invariant measures by linearly mixing $\delta_0\otimes\lambda$ as well as $\delta_x\otimes\delta_1$ for $x>0$ and $\delta_x\otimes\delta_0$ for $x<0$, where $\lambda$ is an arbitrary probability measure on $[0,1]$. The case of sinusoidal $X_t$: Simulations indicate that for small $\omega$ the probability for $Y_t$ to converge to 0 is very small, as most trajectories are attracted to 1 during the first half-period when $X_t$ is positive. In the limit of large $\omega$ the probability of going to either 0 or 1 seems to be 1/2 each.

Comment: Do you want to come into the chatroom https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70145/singular-pde briefly?

Answer (score 2):

Via PDE

We look at the Fokker-Plank or Komogorov forward equations. Let $p(t,x,y)$ be the probability density of the process $(X_t,Y_t)$. From the SDE, we know $p(t,x,y)=p_1(t,x)p_2(t,x,y)$ for some probability densities $p_1$ and $p_2$ and
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}p_1(t,x) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(xp_1(t,x))+\frac12\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}p_1(t,x) \tag1 \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}p_2(t,x,y) &= -\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(xy(1-y)p_2(t,x,y))+\frac12\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\big((xy(1-y))^2p_2(t,x,y)\big) \tag2
\end{align}

> Edit: As pointed out by @S.Surace PDE (2) dropped the terms
>   involving partial derivatives of $x$. I am reconsidering this formulation.

It can be shown, not a trivial task (Maybe I will sketch the proof later.), that the dynamic solution converges to the stationary solution. It satisfies the above equations with both $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}p=0$.

Solving the first stationary equation of Equation (1), $p_1(\infty,x)\propto e^{-x^2}$. Substitute it into the stationary equation of Equation (2), and short hand $p_2(\infty,x,y)$ by $p_2$, we have
$$c(x) = -\frac1xy(1-y)p_2+\frac12\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\big((y(1-y))^2p_2\big)$$
or
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}p_2+2\frac{2(\frac12-y)-\frac1x}{y(1-y)}p_2-\frac{2c(x)}{(y(1-y))^2}=0.$$
The coefficient of $p$ has first order poles at $y=0$ and $y=1$, and the third term on the left hand side has a second order poles at $y=0$ and $y=1$. By the theory of ordinary differential equation, $p_2$ allows poles at $y\in\{0,1\}$. But we do need to ascertain there indeed are poles. The solution for $p_2$ is
$$p_2(x,y) = y^{-2+\frac2x}(1-y)^{-2-\frac2x}\left[2c(x)\int_{\frac12}^yds\, s^{-\frac2x}(1-s)^{\frac2x}+\frac1{16}p_2\Big(x,y=\frac12\Big)\right].$$
Consider the first term. Consider the neighbourhood of $y=0$. The analysis of the neighbourhood of $y=1$ will be similar. The highest order singularities is a first order pole when $x\not=2$. When $x=2$, the highest order singularity is $\frac{\ln y}{y}$. So the first term is never integrable at either end of $y$.

Consider the second term. Assume $p_2\big(x,y=\frac12\big)\not = 0.$ In the neighbourhood of $y=0$, it requires $x\in(0,2)$ for $p_2(x,y)$ to be integrable over $y$. In the neighbourhood of $y=1$, it requires $x\in(-2,0)$. So the second term is never integrable over the whole $y$ interval for $x\not=0$.

Therefore $p_2$ is not integrable. Thus the only stationary solution is $p_2(y)=0$. As a matter of fact one can integrate the above ODE as an algebraic function of the incomplete Beta function with exponents involving $x$.

Therefore the limiting probability distribution is $\delta\big(y(1-y)\big)$.

Comment: Why do we have two different PDEs for $p$? Have you already used separation of variables for (1) and (2), i.e. are they PDEs for the two factors respectively? Also, shouldn't any linear combination of Dirac measures at $0$ and $1$ qualify as stationary measure?

Comment: Yes, you are right in both counts. They are already equations of separated variables. I have now corrected the symbols. Any linear combination of the Dirac measure of $0$ and $1$ should qualify from the derivation so far. Perhaps I should argue further from symmetry that the atomic measure is $\frac12$ for any $x$.

Comment: If I plug the ansatz $p(t,x,y)=p_1(t,x)p_2(t,x,y)$ into the joint Fokker-Planck equation and use (1), I obtain$$p_1(t,x)\frac{\partial}{\partial t}p_2(t,x,y)=-p_1(t,x)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(xy(1-y)p_2(t,x,y))+p_1(t,x)\frac12\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\big((xy(1-y))^2p_2(t,x,y)\big)+xp_1(t,x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}p_2(t,x,y)+\frac{1}{2}p_1(t,x)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}p_2(t,x,y)+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}p_1(t,x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}p_2(t,x,y).$$ How did you arrive at (2)?

Comment: By joint FPE, I mean $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}p(t,x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(xp(t,x,y))+\frac12\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}p(t,x,y)-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(xy(1-y)p(t,x,y))+\frac12\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\big((xy(1-y))^2p(t,x,y)\big)$$.

Comment: It appears more difficult than I thought. I tried expanding $p_2$ and $p$ itself as $y^{\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x)y^n$ to detect the singularity. But I have not found the singularity yet. I am still pondering over it. Maybe it is time to cross-post this question on https://mathoverflow.net/ and present the stationary PDE as a suggestion. I am eager to see what solutions keener minds would bring.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion to post on MO. I will do that later. Basically we want to show that there is no nontrivial solution in $L^1(\mathbb{R}\times[0,1])$ of the eigenvalue problem $\mathcal{A}p=0$ for $$\mathcal{A}=-x\partial_y[y(1-y)\cdot]+\frac12 x^2\partial^2_y[y^2(1-y)^2\cdot]+x\partial_x+\frac12\partial^2_x+q(x)\partial_x,$$ where $q(x)=\partial_x\log p_1(x)$ and $p_1$ is either given by $Ae^{-x^2}$; or more generally, characterize the kernel of $\mathcal{A}$ for $p_1$ any non-zero smooth integrable density function on $\mathbb{R}$. Is that similar to what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, essentially. The first two operators involving $y$ may be the most important. I am hoping we can show they will lead to some poles at $y\in\{0,1\}$. Maybe we should look up the theory of elliptical PDE particularly regarding the singularity of it similar to that in ODE.

Comment: I now posted the question on https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288050/singularity-of-the-solution-of-a-pde-whose-coefficients-have-zeros

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the answer by @Hans (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2554580/227280), we try to show that the stationary measure is not integrable.

We consider the Fokker-Planck equation of the coupled system:

$$\partial_t p(x,y,t)=\partial_x\Big(xp(x,y,t)\Big)+\frac12\partial_x^2p(x,y,t)-x\partial_y\Big(y(1-y)p(x,y,t)\Big)+\frac12x^2\partial_y^2\Big(y^2(1-y)^2p(x,y,t)\Big), \tag1$$

which when integrated over $x$ by parts (assuming that the density and its derivatives vanish for large $x$) can be written as

$$\partial_t \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x,y,t)dx=-\partial_y\Big(y(1-y)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xp(x,y,t)dx\Big)+\frac12\partial_y^2\Big(y^2(1-y)^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2p(x,y,t)dx\Big). \tag2$$

Suppose that a stationary density $p(x,y)$ (sufficiently smooth) exists.
Then the stationary version of (2) reads, for $0<y<1$

$$y(1-y)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xp(x,y)dx-\frac12\partial_y\Big[y^2(1-y)^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2p(x,y)dx\Big]=y(1-y)g(y)-\frac12\partial_y\Big[y^2(1-y)^2f(y)\Big]=0.$$

Solving this ODE for $f$ by integrating over $y$, we have
$$f(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2p(x,y)dx=\frac{1}{y^2(1-y)^2}\Big[\frac{f(\frac12)}{16}+2\int_{\frac12}^yg(z)z(1-z)dz\Big], \quad 0<y<1.$$

Again assuming that $p(x,y)$ is well-behaved, we should also have that

$$\frac12=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2p(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}\times(0,1)}x^2p(x,y)dxdy=\int_0^{1}f(y)dy.$$

It *remains to be shown* that the right-hand side diverges unless $f=g=0$. (As noted in the comments below, this has not been shown yet!)
We could then conclude that $p(x,y)=0$ for $0<y<1$ and that therefore the stationary measure (if it exists at all) must therefore be concentrated on the boundary of $\mathbb{R}\times[0,1]$.

Comment: Fabulous! This can be more directly formulated as integrating the stationary equation of Equation (1) over $x$. I actually thought of this $x$ integration in order to rid $x$ from the joint stationary equation but gave up after realizing it generates not the density function but the first and second moment. I should have forged ahead... Anyway, 1) $f(x,y)$ most likely is not even in $x$ thus $g(y)\not=0$. We need to make some more careful argument regarding the speed $g(y)$ approaches $0$ to ensure the singularity of $f(y)$.

Comment: 2) I do not think you should integrate $z$ from $0$ the point at which we are examining the singularity of $f(y)$, but from, say, $\frac12$.

Comment: Ok. I'm going to simplify the upper part leading to the ODE. I somehow had the feeling that the current business was superflous, but initially I tried to bound the current away from zero and when that did not work I stuck with it. I'm saving it in my files in case we need it later.

Comment: The behavior of $g$ is only important when we assume that $f(1/2)=0$, right?

Comment: Not entirely. We need to ensure $\frac{f(\frac12)}{16}+2\displaystyle\int_{\frac12}^yg(z)z(1-z)dz\not= O(y^2)$ as $y\to 0^+$, say.

Comment: I think we can argue $g(y)<0,\, \forall y\in(0,\frac12]$ if $p(x,y)$ is not almost everywhere $0$ which will make the integral of $g$ above some positive number. Of course $f(y)>0$ under the same condition. We just need to argue carefully.

Comment: I now think the above claim is hard to prove. Also it fails if $X_t\to -X_t$ It seems we are stymied again...

Answer (score 1):

Via SDE but is incomplete.

$$d\ln\frac Y{1-Y}=X\Big[\Big(1+\big(2Y-1\big)X\Big)dt+dV\Big].$$
We just need to show property (P) that the right-hand side when integrated has vanishing probability as $t\to\infty$ within any given arbitrarily large bound. The inverse transformation of $\ln\frac Y{1-Y}$ concentrates the measure outside the bound into intervals arbitrarily close to $\{0,1\}$. We know $V$ has Property (P) while $X$ does not vanish and approaches a stationary distribution. We need to make some estimate for the $dt$ term.

Comment: Thanks for this very helpful set of approaches! I will need some time to try them out. Do you have a suggestion on how to bound the RHS away from zero?

Comment: You are welcome. I am still thinking about it. It seems harder than the PDE approach.